# How to build test project unity for ios. when opened project on Xcode and i dont see simulator ios

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

[image]

I have the problem of not being able to build unity project on iOS simulator. When opening xcode, the iphone and ios virtual machine devices still don't appear. How to build, please help.
i hope resolve issues.
I have the problem of not being able to build unity project on iOS simulator. When opening xcode, the iphone and ios virtual machine devices still don't appear. How to build, please help.
i hope resolve issues.